# Magento2 Change Price by URL parameter

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

Is there a way to change a price using a URL parameter.

For example

**shop.com/?special=true**

changes the prices from `119$ to 99$`

Comment: If there were, then how would you validate it?

Comment: I have two Attributes special=yes; price=99

Answer (score 0):

Since you described everything very briefly, I assumed that you want it. You decide where to place the code, this is just an idea of implementation.

> And objectManager is best taken through DI

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
$param = $request->getParam('special');


if ($param === true) {
   //Get product model
   $newPrice = $product->getPrice() - 20;
   $product->setPrice($newPrice);
   $product->save();
}
```